# Visual Code - Git - Mounted drive VS Linked drive

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with geting Git to run in Visual Code. 
I am using the Git destribution from Cygwin in my git.path setting on a Windows 10 system.

The setup works perfectly if I open the folder through the network location, but when i open the folder after mounting it as a network drive git will not initialize.
I know there have previously been some issues with Cygwin based git support ([Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7998)).

The problem is identical wether the drive is accessed through a VPN or connected directly to the network.

Answer (score 2):

So i came across the issue my self. Problem is the way the Cygwin based git is implemented and named. The solution ended being downloading git-scm for windows ([link](https://git-scm.com/)) then visual code was able to handle the mounted drive just fine.